# Seperate Code Layer to handle events in C#/Java

Tags: java, c#, design-patterns, layer

I want to write a **separate software code Layer** which will do input filtration work and this code run **independently**. *This **script/code layer** will run on every event (e.g., button click etc).* 
I don't want to attach that separate code script to any object.

### **Each time an event happen, it should pass from my separate code layer then, it go to the actual code(function) if my code layer allows it**.

How this is possible.? **How to write independent code layer that my code layer doesn't affect the actual function of an event and work separately**.

I just write this dummy class (for more clarification), this can be work as separate code layer.

```
class FiltrationCodeLayer {
    public int code;
    public void validate(){
        if (code == 200)
        {
            ///Execute the event--How to allow?
        }
        else { 
            // dont execute the event- How to prevent??
        }
    }
}
```

How this validate() method will be call by the event system before running it's actual code like below code snippet. Before firing OnButtonClick method I want to run my above code.

```
class ActualCode
{
    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("button click executed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is "implement" your own controls and override the `On{WhateverEvent}` method:

```
public class MyButton: Button
{
     protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
     {
          if (validate())
          {
             base.OnClick(e);
          }

          //Do nothing or whatever
     }
}
```

The reason being that the event is invoked in `base.OnClick(EventArgs)`.